# Mutliple jQuery Libraries on Same Site (WordPress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I have a client who is trying to add some additional features to their site. They are currently using a self installed jQuery 1.6.1 library that is minified.

I'm trying to install Foundation 4's reveal modal, which requires a newer jQuery library to work correctly. I can get the reveal modal to work if I install a newer jQuery version but it breaks existing scripts on the site.

I am now trying to run the noConflict method that I've found online but I still can't get it to work properly.

In the header I have the following to allow both jQuery libraries to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>  
 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);   
</script>
```

Then in the body of the homepage I have:

```
<script>

$jq(document).foundation();

$jq(".close-reveal-modal").click(function(){
$jq('iframe#vimeo-player').attr('src',''); 
}); 

$jq(".big-link").click(function(){
$jq('iframe#vimeo-player').attr('src','//player.vimeo.com/video/93263452?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&autoplay=1');
}); 

</script>
```

Any ideas how to get this to work in the noConflict mode?

URL to site is: http://developer.creativ3group.com/sodaspeaks/

Comment: What versions of jQuery are you using? jQuery have two supported versions now, 1.x and 2.x. The 2.x has dropped IE8 (and below) support, which makes it more lightweight, but the 1.x is still developed with legacy support and also includes most of the new code.

Comment: Using 1.x - 1.6.2min (included by previous developer) & 1.10.2 (I added for Reveal Module to work)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `noConflict` before adding the second version of jQuery. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq162 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var $jq1102 = $.noConflict(true);   
</script>
```

It would be a much better solution to only use a single library which is the most up to date, although obviously time does not always allow that.

Comment: This didn't work. Getting 2 errors: `TypeError: $.noConfict is not a function var $jq162 = $.noConfict(true);` and `TypeError: $jq1102(...).foundation is not a function $jq1102(document).foundation();`

Comment: Sorry, first one was a typo - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly use `wp_enqueue_script` to enqueue jQuery libraries in WordPress, they will load in the correct order and in no conflict mode.

And, there's no reason to load two jQuery versions; one will do. Load the latest and fix the scripts to work with it. Use `$` instead of `$jq`.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what javascript is loading on your site and the errors.

Comment: I tried the wp_enqueue_script but it didn't pull anything into the header of the site. Not sure if the developer of this site took out stuff to allow this to work, but enqueue doesn't return anything.

Comment: You need to enqueue in functions.php, not in the header.php file.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. `// Load Custom Theme Scripts using Enqueue
function custom_scripts()
{
  
        wp_register_script('customscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0' ); // Custom scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('customscripts'); // Enqueue it!
  
  
    }

add_action('init', 'custom_scripts'); // Add Custom Scripts`